# how to get the text of a href in an element using protractor?

Tags: selenium, protractor

The element I have located here in Chrome dev tools looks like this.

```
<a href="gumby/ui/gumbies/579" title="Mr McGoo meet, Gumby" class="ng-binding">PlayDoh met Mr Potato    Head</a>
```

how to I get the string "`gumby/ui/gumbies/579"` out of it using protractor?

tried everything using `getText()`, `getAttribute('href')` doesn't seem to work for me.

thanks!

Comment: getAttribute('href') is correct, but did you tried using it on the correct element, like this, element(by.cssContainingText("a","PlayDoh met Mr Potato    Head")).getAttribute('href')

Comment: thanks, i got it.    var myTextElm579 = element(by.css('a[href^="gumby/ui/gumbies/579"]'));
        myTextElm579.getAttribute('href').then(function(str){
            console.log('string is= '+str);
        });

Answer (score 8):

getAttribute('href') is correct, but did you tried using it on the correct element, like this:

```
element(by.cssContainingText("a","PlayDoh metMrPotatoHead")).getAttribute('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to get text of an anchor tag and then clicking it
`element(by.partialLinkText('PlayDoh met Mr Potato    Head')).click();`